# A discrete topological space cannot be given a $C^{\infty}$ structure

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

One of problems of the book "Differentiable Manifolds" by Brickell & Clark is as follows (page 38):

Show that a discrete topological space cannot be given a $C^{‎\infty}$ structure.

Here it is what i did:

Suppose that a set $M$ is a discrete topological space and that we then give it a $C^{‎\infty}$ structure. We know that this atlas induces a topological structure. Let $x:U\subset M \to V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be any chart of the given atlas. $x$ is a homeomorphism relative to the discrete topology. Because for any $a\in V$, the set $\{a\}$ is open in the discrete topology. Since $x$ is injective, $x^{−1}(a)$ is a single element of $U$ and $\{x^{−1}(a)\}$ is open in the discrete topology on $M$. Hence $\{x\}$ is continuous. Similarly, it can been shown that $x$ is an open map. Hence it is a homeomorphism.Therefore induced topology on $M$ coincides with the discrete topology. This is where i have stopped !

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: I mean it's not true, there is a unique $C^\infty$ structure on every discrete space; so either the authors made a mistake or they have an unusual definition of manifold

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, but do the authors, perhaps in the definition of a differentiable manifold, explicitly exclude $0$-dimensional manifolds?